# why elements in unordered_multimap are shuffled the order

Tags: c++, c++17, unordered-map

sample program written for `unordered_multimap` and expected is like, elements should be printed in the order in which they are inserted, but in actual output is different. why  elements are not printing in the same order they were inserted. how to modify the program for printing the elements in which order they were inserted.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <unordered_map>

int main ()
{
  std::unordered_multimap<std::string, std::string> mymm;

  mymm.insert(std::make_pair("key6","50"));
  mymm.insert(std::make_pair("key1","150"));
  mymm.insert(std::make_pair("key4","300"));
  mymm.insert(std::make_pair("key2","200"));
  mymm.insert(std::make_pair("key5","100"));
  mymm.insert(std::make_pair("key3","250"));

  for (auto x : mymm)
  {
      std::cout << "key:"<<x.first<<":value:"<<x.second<<std::endl;;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

**output:**

```
key:key5:value:100

key:key4:value:300

key:key1:value:150

key:key3:value:250

key:key6:value:50

key:key2:value:200
```

Comment: Well it is *unordered*. There simply isn't any guaranteed ordering. If you want insertion order then perhaps `std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>>` would be a better solution?

Comment: "expected is like, elements should be printed in the order in which they are inserted," - **Why** would you expect this?

Comment: To understand why it is shuffled read up on how hash tables work.

Comment: @SebastianRedl It's the newbie psychology. Newbies struggle to write code and sometimes the only way to complete a task is to make hopeful assumptions about how C++ works. This can lead to some crazy beliefs about how C++ is, or, like this case, it can lead to beliefs which are plausible but wrong.

Comment: And note you aren't even guaranteed to get the same order from two different runs of your program.

Comment: Putting aside the lack of understanding about how maps are implemented, you can't possibly use a container explicitly called _unordered_ and expect data to be ordered...

Answer (score 1):

The elements are not sorted in any particular order. Thats what the `unorderd..` part of the name suggests. You can iterate them from `begin` till `end` but if your code assumes any particular order than usually thats a bug.

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_multimap):

> Internally, the elements are not sorted in any particular order, but organized into buckets. Which bucket an element is placed into depends entirely on the hash of its key. This allows fast access to individual elements, since once the hash is computed, it refers to the exact bucket the element is placed into.

To have them ordered as inserted you can use `std::vector<std::pair<std::string,std::string>>`.